# Would it be possible to email a result of radio imput Yes/No directly back to me

Tags: javascript, html, css, mailto

Would it be possible to email a result of radio imput Yes/No directly back to me?
HTML, CSS, Javascript

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you are looking for help you need to post the relevant code here, and show what you have done until now.

Comment: It is possible...  you'll need to capture the value of the input, and run the proper code to send an email...  if you can give us what you've got so far, we can help out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in a web page? I suppose the answer is positive.

**Step 1:** Create a web service (or a web page) that once triggered, send emails. Url could be something like:

```
https://api.daveexample.com/emails/sendradioinput/1
```

The last '1' is a parameter can be set in Web Service Client, which indicates true or false value in the radio button.

**Step 2:** In you web page, simply use jQuery to invoke this web service once the radio button is clicked (or anytime if you want it to be triggered.)

```
$.post('https://api.daveexample.com/emails/sendradioinput/1',
     function(data, status) {
          // TODO: check whether the WS is successfully triggered.
     })
```

3. Test it.

Hope it helps. :)